# Using Table Name from Stored Procedure Argument without using Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure that gets the name of a table as one of its arguments.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Job].[DoSomething]
    @tableName VARCHAR (5000)
AS
BEGIN
    --Use @tableName
END
```

I know the column names of the table and all other information required.

I want to use the table name within the stored procedure WITHOUT using dynamic SQL.

Is there any way to get a handle for it (e.g. OBJECT_ID/OBJECT_NAME) and use this handle there where I usually would use the table name in a SQL statement.

E.G. (Pseudocode):

```
SELECT * 
FROM OBJECT_ID(@tableName)
```

Comment: Having a table name as a parameter of any stored proc/function is a bad idea. If you insist on it (you shouldn't really) you have no other option than to use dynamic sql.

Comment: Table, schema and column names cannot be parametrized in "regular" SQL - if you **must do this** (and I believe most of the time it's a bad design), then you have **no other choice** than to use dynamic SQL.